# where to check snowflake kafka connector logs

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect

i am trying to implement snowflake kafka connector to ingest data into snowflake in real time. Kafka setup on personal system is completed and i am able to push events and subscribe to events in real time successfully. However the snowflake kafka connector is not working properly and not creating the table which it should as its default property. I want to check the kafka connector logs to see where it is failing however i am not able to find the snowflake kafka connector logs. Below are the points which i have checked.

1. tested the key pair authentication in snowflake which is working
2. user has the access to create stage ,pipe and tables on the target db and schema

below is the log directory

```
server.properties => log.dirs=E:/kafka_logs/kafka_server
```

i see one log file created at

```
E:/kafka_logs/kafka_server/<topic_name>-0/0000000.log but the data is not in readable format
```

Can one please guide where i can check the SF kafka connector logs for trouble shooting ?

Answer (score 0):

The logs would be generated based on the driver configuration and properties that are set for the connector.

The documentation link which details these flags is: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors#kafka

Based on these flags, you can get more specific and verbose level logs to understand what exactly is going wrong in the integration.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-ts

Comment: i was just done trying the method at above link . Here is the config in log4j.properties log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/server.log
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/connector.log ....... However the connector.log file did not create. i see the server.log file which was getting created already.

Answer (score 0):

**Root Cause** : i missed the last step to start the connector :)

```
E:/kafka_2.12-3.6.0/bin/windows/connect-standalone.bat E:/kafka_2.12-3.6.0/config/connect-standalone.properties E:/kafka_2.12-3.6.0/config/SF_connect.properties
```

**SF-Connector Logs** : no separate file got created. SF connector logs got pushed to E:\kafka_2.12-3.6.0\logs\connect.log

```
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] pipe SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_demo_kafka_topic_sf_stream_PIPE_hello_world_tbl_0, flush pipe: demo_kafka_topic_sf_stream/hello_world_tbl/0/1544_1603_1700557085192.json.gz (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkServiceV1:79)
[2023-11-21 14:28:35,763] INFO [demo_kafka_topic_sf_stream|task-0] 
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] pipe SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_demo_kafka_topic_sf_stream_PIPE_hello_world_tbl_0, flush pipe: demo_kafka_topic_sf_stream/hello_world_tbl/0/1604_1663_1700557115302.json.gz (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkServiceV1:79)
[2023-11-21 14:28:38,414] INFO [demo_kafka_topic_sf_stream|task-0] 
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] searched 3 files in ingest report, found 2
```